# How to store android spinner selected value to parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform, android-spinner

I want to store android spinner selected value into parse.com, where I created another column name as branch. so whenever any user sign up and select any item from drop down menu then it will store into the branch column name as a fix string.
Here is my sign up activity code.

```
package com.goyllo.gecrajkot;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;


public class SignUp extends ActionBarActivity implements      AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {



protected EditText mUsername;
protected EditText mPassword;
protected EditText mEmail;
protected Button mSignUpButton;
protected Spinner mSpinnerBranch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);


    mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UsernameField);
    mPassword =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PasswordField);
    mEmail =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailField);
    mSpinnerBranch = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_branch);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.branch_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerBranch.setAdapter(adapter);


    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();


            username = username.trim();
            password = password.trim();
            email = email.trim();

            if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                 .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else{
                // create the new user
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                newUser.setUsername(username);
                newUser.setPassword(password);
                newUser.setEmail(email);
                newUser.put("branch", SelectedBranch);


                newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                        if (e == null) {
                            //success!

                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {
            // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
           String SelectedBranch = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Another interface callback
        }

    });
}
```

I have problem with below line code. Don't know what I did mistake. Or if you have any other suggestion, then please describe here.

newUser.put("branch", SelectedBranch);

Comment: There's a close reason called "why is the code not working".  As written, this question fits it perfectly.  Please: 1) post only code related to newUser and SelectedBranch, 2) present evidence of it not working (what do you expect, what does it do proven by logging etc), 3) provide at least one theory about why and show what you've done to test that theory.  Questions asked this way provide useful tools for later readers.

Comment: Signup activity run perfect when I am not using spinner and it's class, but I need to store users branch name, for further steps (like push notification to specific branch users.)

Comment: Did you add initialize to your code?